# Am I doing anything wrong with my double NAT?

Tags: networking, router, security, nat

I have added two routers in double NAT configuration, in order to protect my inner network from some risky devices that exist on my outer network (the private network of my internet-facing router).

(Now, I am not sure if that still provides protection, after [NAT slipstream](https://thehackernews.com/2021/01/new-attack-could-let-remote-hackers.html) attacks are made public, but anyway... If you have any feedback on that, feel free to share your info!)

So, essentially, I have DHCP disabled on both routers and only work with static IPs everywhere. I know that having two DHCP servers can cause havoc sometimes and that is not my issue.

The inner router connects to the internet through the outer router (provided by my ISP).

I have set some public DNS servers on both routers (like 1.1.1.1, 8.8.8.8, etc), although I have doubts if they really use them. I have the same DNS servers set on my OS.

Everything seems to work pretty nicely, until it suddenly doesn't!

I sometimes lose the internet connection. Restarting the rooters sometimes restores the connection, but the problem might reappear hours later. One time, restart didn't fix anything, but maybe my ISP was meddling with their cables (I contacted them and they said they were people messing things up nearby that day).

So...

1. Does anyone know what I should pay attention to, when using this setup?
2. Any idea what may be wrong? I am trying to figure out if the problem is on the ISP side, but not sure how... Will `tracert 1.1.1.1` the next time it happens do it? Probably, right? I should see where the packets stop along the route, right?

Comment: generally speaking, if it (your nat forwarding) works, it works, and if it doesn't, it doesn't. you may have a hardware issue, or contention with your ISP, but its unlikely you are doing something wrong with the double-nat forwarding if it works sometimes.

Comment: Do you have the DHCP client disabled on the WAN side of the outer router? If so, the ISP might be trying to change your public IP, and the router not going along with it. BTW, for troubleshooting purposes, if it fails try testing from the outer private network (i.e. between the two routers), so you're only testing one layer of NAT.

Comment: @GordonDavisson No, I don't even see an option for DHCP on WAN. But I think the problem was with my ISP from the beginning. I have contacted them, they adjusted some quality parameters (that also lowered my connection speed a bit), and it seems to be better now. Not fixed, but better. Also the problem happened mainly during work hours, so I guess this makes some sense, now with the lockdowns...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tests and communication with my ISP, everything suggests that the problem was caused by my ISP.

It is terrible...